# how to get the text of the action associated with an icontributionitem

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a MenuManager (instance of `IMenuManager`) and to this menumanager a `ContributionItem` is added (instance of `ContributionItem`). There is an action (instance of `IAction`) associated with this contribution item.

The problem is I could not type cast the `ContributionItem` to `ActionContributionItem`. hence I'm unable to get the menu/action text of the action associated with the menuitem.

Is there a way to get the 'Menu Text' or 'Action Text' of a ContributionItem?

Comment: What is the actual type of the `ContributioinItem` that hold the action?

Comment: Rudiger, Thanks for the reply.

It is of type ContributionItem.

Comment: `ContributionItem` is an abstract class so it cannot be the actual type.

Comment: They have created an anonymous object implementing the 'fill()' method